# Cleaning DataFrame: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

[see image here - code python pandas error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuovz.png)

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/content/data_mining/merged_dataset.csv')

#Cleaning data frame

#Delete rows where year is less than 1900:
for x in df.index:
  if df.loc[x, 'startYear'] < 1900:
    df.drop(x, inplace = True)

#Delete rows that are not movies:
for x in df.index:
  if df.loc[x, 'titleType'] != 'movie':
    df.drop(x, inplace = True)

#Delete all adult films:
for x in df.index:
  if df.loc[x, 'isAdult'] == '1':
    df.drop(x, inplace = True)


print(df.to_string())
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-672b76e68b2d> in <cell line: 4>()
      3 #Delete rows where year is less than 1900:
      4 for x in df.index:
----> 5   if df.loc[x, 'startYear'] < 1900:
      6     df.drop(x, inplace = True)
      7 
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

In my dataset I am trying to delete all rows of content which came before the year 1900. The entire column for 'startYear' is all numbers but I cannot compare it with the number 1900 as it states that 'startYear' is apparently a string and not an integer like the value '1900.'

Comment: Wouldn't the problem be solved if you changed the `startyear` column to `int`?
What is the question asking? Is the question asking how to change it to `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because column `startYear` is a string. You can convert it to int first then filter dataframe. Here is the sample code

```
# Convert 'startYear' column to numeric (ignore errors for non-convertible values)
df['startYear'] = pd.to_numeric(df['startYear'], errors='coerce')

# Filter the DataFrame based on the condition (remove year < 1900)
df = df[df['startYear'] >= 1900]

print(df)
```